# Python 2.7 Unicode Dict

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm wondering how I can encode Dicts in Python 2.7. When I do the following:

```
# coding=ISO-8859-1
Programmer = {'v': ["1","2x","3","4","5"]}
Programmer.update({'x': ["1","2x","3","4","5"]})
Programmer.update({'y': ["1","2x","3","4","5"]})
Programmer.update({'z': ["1","2x","3","4","5"]})
Programmer.update({'æ': ["1","2x","3","4","5"]})
Programmer.update({'ø': ["1","2x","3","4","5"]})
Programmer.update({'å': ["1","2x","3","4","5"]})
print Programmer
```

I get:

```
{'v': ['1', '2x', '3', '4', '5'], '\xe5': ['1', '2x', '3', '4', '5'], '\xf8': ['1', '2x', '3', '4', '5'], '\xe6': ['1', '2x', '3', '4', '5'], 'y': ['1', '2x', '3', '4', '5'], 'x': ['1', '2x', '3', '4', '5'], 'z': ['1', '2x', '3', '4', '5']}
```

And what I want is:

```
{'v': ['1', '2x', '3', '4', '5'], 'å': ['1', '2x', '3', '4', '5'], 'ø': ['1', '2x', '3', '4', '5'], 'æ': ['1', '2x', '3', '4', '5'], 'y': ['1', '2x', '3', '4', '5'], 'x': ['1', '2x', '3', '4', '5'], 'z': ['1', '2x', '3', '4', '5']}
```

**EDIT:**

This is my working code:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import locale

global Programmer
Programmer = {u'v': ["1","2x","3","4","5"]}
Programmer.update({u'x': ["1","2x","3","4","5"]})
Programmer.update({u'y': ["1","2x","3","4","5"]})
Programmer.update({u'z': ["1","2x","3","4","5"]})
Programmer.update({u'æ': ["1","2x","3","4","5"]})
Programmer.update({u'ø': ["1","2x","3","4","5"]})
Programmer.update({u'å': ["1","2x","3","4","5"]})

class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    NumGridRows = 3
    NumButtons = 3

    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()
        styleComboBox = QtGui.QComboBox()
        styleComboBox.addItem("UI Item01")
        styleLabel = QtGui.QLabel("&UI Text:")
        styleLabel.setBuddy(styleComboBox)
        opgaveComboBox = QtGui.QComboBox()
        opgaveComboBox.addItem(u"v")
        opgaveComboBox.addItem(u"x")
        opgaveComboBox.addItem(u"å")

        opgaveLabel = QtGui.QLabel("&Opgave:")
        opgaveLabel.setBuddy(opgaveComboBox)

        self.programComboBox = QtGui.QComboBox()
        self.programComboBox.addItem("UI item02")
        programLabel = QtGui.QLabel("&Program:")
        programLabel.setBuddy(self.programComboBox)


        opgaveComboBox.activated[str].connect(self.changeOpgave)

        topLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        topLayout.addWidget(styleLabel)
        topLayout.addWidget(styleComboBox)
        #topLayout.addStretch(1)

        topLayoutB = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        topLayoutB.addWidget(opgaveLabel)
        topLayoutB.addWidget(opgaveComboBox)
        #topLayoutB.addStretch(1)

        topLayoutC = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        topLayoutC.addWidget(programLabel)
        topLayoutC.addWidget(self.programComboBox)



        mainLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(topLayout, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        mainLayout.addLayout(topLayoutB, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        mainLayout.addLayout(topLayoutC, 2, 0, 1, 2)
        mainLayout.setRowStretch(1, 1)
        mainLayout.setRowStretch(2, 1)
        mainLayout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        mainLayout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)



        self.changeStyle('Cleanlooks')
        self.setWindowTitle("temp test")

    def changeOpgave(self, opgaveName):
        self.programComboBox.clear()
        print "begin 01"
        print Programmer[opgaveName]

        if not opgaveName in Programmer:
            print "begin 02"
            self.programComboBox.addItem("Andet")
        else:
            print "go"
            for item in Programmer[opgaveName]:
                self.programComboBox.addItem(item)

    def changeStyle(self, styleName):
        QtGui.QApplication.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create(styleName))
        self.changePalette()

    def changePalette(self):
        QtGui.QApplication.setPalette(QtGui.QApplication.style().standardPalette())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = Dialog()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(dialog.exec_())
```

I get

```
KeyError: PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'v')
KeyError: PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'x')
KeyError: "PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'\xe5')
```

When trying to select from the "opgave" list 
(error thrown at line 79)

Comment: You need to read up on the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html), I'd say. Also, Python prints strings as representations, where non-ASCII and non-printable characters are represented by escape sequences. The *value* hasn't changed.

Comment: Yea, did read that one, but i guess i just didnt understand it fully. The problem is when i later in my code start comparing it with "if" statements i get key errors "KeyError: u'\xc5'"

Comment: Then something *else* is wrong at that point. The dictionary in your example does not include the character `'\xc5'`, so that is no surprise.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, changed it to a capital "Å". But let me show you some sample code here: http://pastebin.com/i6BWgSZ3 using PyQt4. If i under "Opgave" select "å" i get this error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\DebugForStackoverflow.py", line 82, in changeOpgave
        print Programmer[unicode(opgaveName)]
    KeyError: u'\xe5'

Comment: You are using `unicode()` calls that are *not needed*. You do not need to turn a dictionary into a `unicode()` string when testing for key membership, for example; that makes your code *very inefficient*. You have a dictionary with `str` keys but are then testing with `unicode()` values, which leads to automatic comparisons between `unicode()` and `str()` values, these use the default encoding (which is not the same as the source code encoding) and that leads to mismatches. `u'\xe5'` is not *necessarily* the same value as `'\xe5'`, depending on the encoding used!

Comment: How should i store them then? If i remove the "unicode()" part i get the "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe5' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: That is the automatic conversion playing; the `unicode()` value is being compared to all the bytestring keys in the dictionary. Use unicode keys throughout instead.

Comment: You mean like: "Programmer.update({u'æ': ["1","2x","3","4","5"]})" ?

Comment: then i get: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: **Where** are you getting that exception? You are again mixing bytecode strings and `unicode()` values somewhere and automatic conversion is taking place.

Comment: When using `unicode()` on a string, you really should specify the encoding: `unicode(somestring, 'latin1')` for example. Or use the `str.decode()` method: `somestring.decode('latin1')`. Otherwise Python uses the default, which is ASCII. This is all laid out in the Unicode HOWTO, btw.

Comment: Thanks alot for your patience and helping hand!.. I found the unicode thing i removed it.. http://pastebin.com/CGKyqqHE 
if i select V or X i get:
"KeyError: PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'v')" and "KeyError: PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'x')" and with å i get KeyError: "PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'\xe5')"

Comment: could you post your working code as an answer? That would be helpful

Comment: Have added it to the main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combobox callback is handed a `PyQt4.QtCore.QString()` object, not a unicode string. Your dictionary on the other hand should use `unicode()` keys (which is the right thing to do).

Convert the `QString()` object to a unicode value first:

```
def changeOpgave(self, opgaveName):
    opgaveName = unicode(opgaveName)
```

This works because the `QString()` object already holds unicode data and provides Python with the right hooks to make this conversion without needing to re-encode the data with an explicit codec.

Once the `opgaveName` value is a unicode key, you can use it to compare it against your dictionary.

Note that you can just define the dictionary without `.update()` calls:

```
Programmer = {
    u'v': ["1","2x","3","4","5"],
    u'x': ["1","2x","3","4","5"],
    u'y': ["1","2x","3","4","5"],
    u'z': ["1","2x","3","4","5"],
    u'æ': ["1","2x","3","4","5"],
    u'ø': ["1","2x","3","4","5"],
    u'å': ["1","2x","3","4","5"],
}
```

The `global` keyword has no meaning where you are using it; that keyword only makes sense inside functions, and is redundant here.

Comment: You my friend, are the best! It makes perfectly sense now.

Answer (score 0):

may be like this:

```
print "{",
for key, value in Programmer.items():
    print "'%s'" % key, ':', value, ',',
print "}"
```

when you do print then this will print `str(Programmers)` but inside dict uses `repr(key)` and `repr(value)`. The content does not change, it will just be printed differently.

Comment: Ahhh... ok! Thanks. But as stated in my answer to Martijn i get some errors down the line when comparing the value "KeyError: u'\xc5'"

Comment: Encoding is something I am not sure of and because of this I always use `# coding=UTF-8` and `unicode` strings with `u''` to not get into the hell of differently encoded files.