# Reliable way of handling non-ASCII characters in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters

I have a column a spreadsheet whose header contains non-ASCII characters thus:

```
'ï»¿Campaign'
```

If I pop this string into the interpreter, I get:

```
'\xc3\xaf\xc2\xbb\xc2\xbfCampaign'
```

The string is one the keys in the `rows` of a `csv.DictReader()`

When I try to populate a new dict with with the `value` of this key:

```
spends['ï»¿Campaign'] = 2
```

I get:

```
Key Error: '\xc3\xaf\xc2\xbb\xc2\xbfCampaign'
```

If I print the value of the keys of row, I can see that it is `'\xef\xbb\xbfCampaign'`

Obviously then I can just update my program to access this key thus:

```
spends['\xef\xbb\xbfCampaign']
```

But is there a "better" way of doing this, in Python? Indeed, if the value of this key every changes to contain other non-ASCII characters, what is an all-encompassing way of handling any all non-ASCII characters that may arise?

Comment: try `spends[u'æ'] = 2` and see [this similar question for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437245/python-2-7-unicode-dict)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you should decode a bytestring into Unicode text using the corresponding character encoding as soon as possible on input. And, in reverse, encode Unicode text into a bytestring as late as possible on output. Some APIs such as `io.open()` can do it implicitly so that your code sees only Unicode.

Unfortunately, `csv` module does not support Unicode directly on Python 2. See [`UnicodeReader`, `UnicodeWriter` in the doc examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples). You could create their analog for `csv.DictReader` or as an alternative just pass utf-8 encoded bytestrings to `csv` module.

Comment: I presume your first `cvs` was intended to be read `csv`. :) I strongly encourage folks to take your suggested route of implicit codecs wherever and whenever possible, such as via `io.open()`.  It really makes their lives a huge whole lot easier. I sometimes get so used to this that I forget there's any other way — until I bump up against a library that only handles bytes data instead of character data. Suddenly you drop out of the comfortable constructed world of a high-level language into the rabbit hole of device drivers and bit twiddling and terrors even worse than those.

Comment: `csv` is such an example. in Python 2.x, `csv` reads *bytes*, rather than *text*. The post linked by Sebastian gives a good way to at least deal with the conversion in a single place.

Answer (score 5):

Your specific problem is the first three bytes of the file, `"\xef\xbb\xbf"`. That's the UTF-8 encoding of the *byte order mask* and often prepended to text files to indicate they're encoded using UTF-8. You should strip these bytes. See [Removing BOM from gzip'ed CSV in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899939/removing-bom-from-gziped-csv-in-python).

Second, you're decoding with the wrong codec. `"ï»¿"` is what you get if you decode those bytes using the Windows-1252 character set. That's why the bytes look different if you use these characters in a source file. See the [Python 2 Unicode howto](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html).

Comment: you could use `'utf-8-sig'` encoding to deal with BOM automatically.