# Is it possible to access list values if the key has a special character in it in Python 3?

Tags: python, csv

I've got an interesting problem.
I get a report per email and parse the CSV with `csv.DictReader` like so:

```
with open(extracted_report_uri) as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        report.append(row)
```

Unfortunately the CSV contains one column called `"eCPM (€)"` which leaves me with a list like so:
`{'eCPM (€)': '1.42'}`

Python really does not like a `print(report[0]['eCPM (€)'])` as it refuses to accept the Euro-sign as a key.

I tried creating an unicode string with the € inside and use that as the key but this also doesnt work.
I'd either like to access the value (obviously) as is, or simply get rid of the €.

The suggested duplicates answer is covering the topic of removing BOM rather than accessing my key. I also tried it via `report[0][u'eCPM (€)']` as suggested in the comments there. Does not work. `KeyError: 'eCPM (�)'`

The suggestion from the comment also doesn't work for me. Using `report[0][u'eCPM (%s)' % '€'.encode('unicode-escape')]` results in `KeyError: "eCPM (b'\\\\u20ac')"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reliable way of handling non-ASCII characters in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276483/reliable-way-of-handling-non-ascii-characters-in-python)

Comment: That key works for me in IDLE. What error do you get?

Comment: @user193661: Exactly what I wrote, the KeyError. I am using PyCharm  set to CRLF/UTF-8 under Win7 for development. That might be a part of the problem. The console also shows the € in the command as � like so: `print(reports[0][0][u'eCPM (%s)' % '�'.encode('unicode-escape')])
KeyError: "eCPM (b'\\\\u20ac')"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research I found out how to properly do this it seems. As I've seen all sorts of issues on Google/Stackoverflow with BOM/UTF-8 and DictReader here's the complete code:

Situation:
You got a CSV file that has Byte Order Mark (BOM)`0xEF,0xBB,0xBF` with special characters like `€äöµ@` or similar in the fieldname and want to read it properly to access the key:value pairs lateron.

In my example the CSV has a fieldname `eCPM (€)` and this' how it works:

```
import csv
report = []

with open('test.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        report.append(row)

print(report[0][u'eCPM (€)'])
```

Before this solution I removed the BOM with a function, but there's really no need for this. If you use `open()` with `encoding='utf-8-sig` it'll automagically handle the BOM correctly and properly encode the whole file.

And with `[u'€']` you can easily access the values of the generated list unicode style.

Thanks for the comments that brought me on the right track!